# MEF + WCF + DLL plugins

Tags: c#, wcf, mef

I've found the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) to create applications with support to plugins in real-time.

My idea is create a WCF with one function:

```
public ResultObject ExecuteFunction(string moduleName, string functionName, string[] properties);
```

I.E:

C:/Plugins:
    - ModuleA.dll
    - ModuleB.dll
    - ModuleC.dll

In a ConsoleApp just a simple function call:

```
ResultObject result = myWCF.ExecuteFunction("ModuleA","SumNumbers",new String[]{ "1" , "2" });
```

The idea is create infinity modules and just put inside Plugin's folder and WCF be able to recognize the new modules and run perfectly.

I've created an ConsoleAppliction with MEF using this idea, but how I can do this project in a WCF project?

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work with WCF?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Maybe work, but I don't know how call dynamically modules and functions